# Page scrolls infinitely in Firefox if i'm using a sticky element

Tags: css, firefox, sticky

I have a simple content/sidebar layout with a sticky sidebar. In firefox if the sidebar is taller than the content, you can scroll down infinitely, the scrollbar just gets smaller and smaller. Here is a demo:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

p {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
  <nav></nav>
</div>
```

Works fine in Safari and Chrome, but i'm unable to fix this in Firefox. Any ideas what might be the issue? Thanks

Comment: position sticky is still an experimental property. I'd suggest trying a workaround with position: absolute or relative. And maybe open a bug at buzilla

Comment: it seems like the green div make impossible to reach the end of the scroller, i think it's a firefox bug.